# after a network call, and after checking the data in the database, I cannot remove the duplicates in the set

Tags: java, android, duplicates, set

hi i can't add all users to  set.
After making a network call, to get all posts, I want to add some items in Set  (I use Set to avoid duplicates).My code is:

```
public static void send_request_post(String sid, int did, Activity activity, AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity) {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity);
        JSONObject requestParam = new JSONObject();
        String GET_POST = "https://helme/cc/helpme.php";
        Set<User> user= new HashSet<User>();
        Log.d("main_activity", "fino a qui funziona");
        try {
            requestParam.put("sid", sid);
            requestParam.put("did", did);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.POST,
                GET_POST,
                requestParam,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) { 
                        try {
                            JSONArray sid_user111 = response.getJSONArray("posts");
                            for (int j = 0; j < sid_user111.length(); j++) {
                                JSONObject postss = sid_user111.getJSONObject(j);            
                                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        try {
                                            if(!(Model_user.getInstance
                                                    (activity.getApplicationContext()).getcontainsuid
                                                    (postss.getString("author")))){
                                                user.add(new User(postss.getString("author"),
                                                        postss.getString("authorName"), String.valueOf(0),
                                                        postss.getString("pversion")));
                                                Log.d("main_activity_user","ok user add");

                                            }} catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }).start();
                            }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }
                });
        MainActivity.requestQueue.add(req);
    }
```

Now User Dao has the method:

```
@Query("select Exists(select uid from User where uid =:useruid)")
    Boolean loadAllByuid(String useruid);
```

which checks if author is present in the database.
And my class Model_user have methods:

```
public class Model_user {
    private static Model_user theinstance = null;
    private static AppDatabase userDAOs = null;
    public static synchronized Model_user getInstance() {
        if (theinstance == null) {
            theinstance = new Model_user();
        }
        return theinstance;
    }
    public static synchronized Model_user getInstance(Context c) {
        if (theinstance == null) {
            userDAOs = Room.databaseBuilder(c, AppDatabase.class, "user_db").build();
            theinstance = new Model_user();
        }
        return theinstance;
    }
```

Having 10 users of which some are duplicates, my question is: why if I want to add each user to the Set  within the thread, it also adds the duplicate users? In fact the log prints me 10 times:"ok user add". Why?

Comment: You don't check if the set already contains the user. You just call `user.add(...)` and let the `Set` handle the duplicate check. Afterwards you call the log, which get executed because again, you don't perform any checks. You should do `if(!set.add(...))` to check if the log should be printed. [Set#add](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add(E))

Comment: hi in User.class i have this methods for to remove duplicates from Set: public boolean equals(Object o) and  public int hashCode().

Comment: `why if I want to add each user to the Set within the thread, it also adds the duplicate users?` -> it does not add them, which you will see, if you debug the `Set` contents. `In fact the log prints me 10 times:"ok user add". Why?` -> because you call `Log.d("main_activity_user","ok user add");` without checking if the user is already present in the `Set`. As you have 10 users, the log is printed 10 times

Comment: so first I have to check if the user is present in the Set and then call set.add (new User (...)) right?but what i'm wondering is: by implementing the equals () and hascode () methods, shouldn't Set already delete the duplicates?

Comment: With `equals()` and `hashCode()`, the set just check if the element already exists. If it does then `Set#add` returns false. If the element doesn't exists, then `Set#add` returns true.  Hence my suggestion from the first comment to wrap the `Set#add` call in an if like this `if(!set.add(...))`

Comment: thank you very much, but if I want to print the print from the size of the Set <User> outside the thread, how can I do? because if I log ("main_activity, String.valueOf (user.size ()) this prints me 0

Comment: Becaust the threads aren't done yet. You need for the threads to finish